# Product Discount Groups and Customer Groups

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog-price-rules, discount, customer-group

How can I set-up Product Discount Groups and add different prices for the Customers Groups?

I want to import different products in Magento: E.g. one sheet has 30.000 products. The products are sorted in around 30 Product Discount Groups, so every Product Discount Groups has around 1000 products. I want to have the Product Discount Group information added with the product, e.g. Product 1000 is part of the Product Group AA.

Then I want the option to configure different prizes/discounts of the Product Discount Groups for the Customer Groups. E.g. Customer Group Retailers 0%, Group Wholesaler 30%, Group Consumer Price * 1,3.

How could I do this the best way?

Comment: What version of Magento?

Comment: Magento Version 1.9.0.1

Comment: You would have to create the customer groups, then import the group price with a manual calculation. Group price is not set to work off a calculation.